# use mail-service.xml with Wildfly 8 for sending Mail on server start - IllegalStateException

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly-8, mail-server

I am trying to use mail-service.xml in Wildfly 8. It has to send mail on server startup. I get this error when I start Wildfly. My file is located in the deployments folder.

This is the error:

```
    2015-07-08 10:20:22,884 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mail-service.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mail-service.xml".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "mail-service.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017224: Failed to parse service xml ["/C:/foo/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/mail-service.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state START_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA, SPACE, ENTITY_REFERENCE, DTD valid for getText() 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getText(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.getText(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.unexpectedContent(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:638)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.parseAttribute(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:386)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.parseMBean(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.readElement(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.readElement(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:95)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my mail-service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <server>
      <mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService" name="jboss:service=Mail">
        <attribute name="JNDIName">java:/Mail</attribute>
        <attribute name="User">user</attribute>
        <attribute name="Password">password</attribute>
        <attribute name="Configuration">
           <!-- Test -->
           <configuration>
              <!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
              <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
              <property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

              <!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
              <property name="mail.user" value="user"/>

              <!-- Change to the mail server  -->
              <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="foo.pop3"/>

              <!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
              <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="foo.smtp"/>

              <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
              <property name="mail.from" value="foo@foo.com"/>

              <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
              <property name="mail.debug" value="false"/>
           </configuration>
        </attribute>
      </mbean>

    </server>
```

I checked already my XML and could not find any XML error.

Comment: Is there someone, at least with a suggestion?

Comment: Your XML looks ok. Have you tried removing the first line (the xml definition)? and, are you sure that this is the file that is being read from jboss? is it really located in C:/foo/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/mail-service.xml?

Comment: it is located in my the deployments folder of wildfly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it (or even if it can be done) by using a mail-service.xml file as in JBoss 5/6, but you can do it by registering the resource as in JBoss 7 in two different ways:

- Editing standalone.xml in ${wildfly-home}/standalone/configuration: check [this link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS720EmailSessionConfigurtion-EnglishVersion)
- Using the admin console in localhost:9990/console: check [this link](http://www.opensiam.com/2014/06/wildfly-8-sending-email-using-gmail.html) or [this other](http://khozzy.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/how-to-send-mails-from-jboss-wildfly.html)

Regards,